# Analysis of Steady State Probability for Markov Process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

I have a balance equation, representing a Markov Chain, which yields
$$
(K - z) \pi(Z_c = z) = (\lambda_c + (z+1)x) \pi(Z_c = z+1)
$$
where K is the maximum state of the server. The term $\lambda_c$ and $x$ are the constants.

From this, the following steady-state probability is obtained:
$$
\pi(Z_c = z) = \pi(Z_c = K) x^{(K-z)} * C
$$
where C is given by
$$
{K+\frac{\lambda_c}{x}}\choose{K-z}
$$

The approximation of $\pi(Z_c = K)$ is given by:
$$
\pi(Z_c = K) = (\sum_{y=0}^{K} x^y {K+ \frac{\lambda_c}{y}\choose{y} })^{-1}
$$

Can anybody help me in approximation $\pi(Z_c = K)$? How is $\pi(Z_c = K)$ approximated?